# cannot declare variable 'test' to be of abstract type 'OurStack<int>'

Tags: c++, stack, abstract-class, virtual

I've been looking at similar answers and they all had the parameters wrong or typos.

I'm trying to create a stack of type int, but I'm getting problems with the push function.

The exact error is:

```
 OurStack<int> test;
               ^
In file included from StackTester.cpp:5:0:
OurStack.h:7:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'OurStack<int>':
 class OurStack : public StackInterface<T>
       ^
In file included from OurStack.h:4:0,
                 from StackTester.cpp:5:
StackInterface.h:11:15: note:   bool StackInterface<T>::push(const T&) [with T = int]
  virtual bool push(const T& newEntry) = 0;
```

Here's my code:

## StackInterface.h

```
/** @file StackInterface.h */ 
#ifndef _STACK_INTERFACE
#define _STACK_INTERFACE 
template<class T> class StackInterface 
 { public: 

    /** Sees whether this stack is empty. @return True if the stack is empty, or false if not. */ 
virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

/** Adds a new entry to the top of this stack. @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the top of the stack. @param newEntry The object to be added as a new entry. @return True if the addition is successful or false if not. */ 
virtual bool push(const T& newEntry) = 0; 

/** Removes the top of this stack. @post If the operation was successful, the top of the stack has been removed. @return True if the removal is successful or false if not. */ 
virtual bool pop() = 0;

/** Returns the top of this stack. @pre The stack is not empty. @post The top of the stack has been returned, and the stack is unchanged. @return The top of the stack. */
virtual T peek() const = 0;
};

// end StackInterface 
#endif
```

## OurStack.h

```
#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_

#include "StackInterface.h"

template <class T>
class OurStack : public StackInterface<T>
{
    private:
    std::stack<T> ourStack;

    public:
        OurStack();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool push(const T& newEntry) const;
        bool pop();
        T peek() const;

};
#include "OurStack.cpp"
#endif
```

## OurStack.cpp

```
#include "OurStack.h"

template <class T>
OurStack<T>::OurStack()
{
    //not much to do between these
}

template <class T>
bool OurStack<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return ourStack.empty();
}

template <class T>
bool OurStack<T>::push(const T& newEntry) const
{
    ourStack.push(&newEntry);
    return true;
}

template <class T>
bool OurStack<T>::pop()
{
    if(ourStack.empty() == true)
        return false;
    else
    {
        ourStack.pop();
        return true;
    }
}

template <class T>
T OurStack<T>::peek() const
{
    return ourStack.top();
}
```

## StackTester.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include "OurStack.h"

using namespace std;

OurStack<int> test;
int any;

int main()
{
    cout<<"press any number";
    cin>>any;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: nope, notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `bool OurStack<T>::push(const T& newEntry) const;` but your base class declares `bool push(const T& newEntry);`. `push` is not `const`. Use the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword to avoid these issues.

```
template <class T>
class OurStack : public StackInterface<T>
{
    private:
    std::stack<T> ourStack;

    public:
        OurStack();
        bool isEmpty() const override; // Compiles
        bool push(const T& newEntry) const override; // Doesn't compile
        bool pop() override; // Compiles
        T peek() const override; // Compiles

};
```

Comment: Thanks, it was const in the provided StackInterface and it seemed odd, must have been a mistake

edit: no it wasn't, I made the mistake.  probably better

Answer (score 0):

How can a push function:

```
   bool push(const T& newEntry) const;
```

possibly be const?

Also, names like this:

```
   _STACK_H_
```

are reserved for the implementation. Simply use:

```
   STACK_H
```